# form prepopulation with jquery (making it scaleable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, population

I have the jquery below which basically pre-populates a text box. (It actually populates a span above the text box which is then positioned over the text box. Then when the span is clicked, it hides it and focuses on the text box.) This way I don't have to add the pre-populated values into the form field, so if the user submits it won't submit the populated values with it. Right now this seems to be working, but the problem is I have about text boxes on the page that I want to have this functionality all with different pre-populated values. I'm trying to figure out a way to make this scale, so I just need basically one function, and depending on the ID of the text box it will populate different data into the span above. Any help would be great!

Working jquery code for only 1 text box: (I really don't want to write this function over and over again for each text box

```
if($("#workphone").val().length == 0)
{
    var overlayCellPhone = $("<span class='prepopulation'>1234567890</span>");
    $("#workphone").parent().prepend(overlayCellPhone);


    $(".prepopulation").click(function(){
        $("#workphone").focus()
        $(".prepopulation").hide();
    });

    $("#workphone").blur(function(){
        if($("#workphone").val().length == 0)
        {
            $(".prepopulation").show();
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTML5 allows you to set placeholder text for input fields](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder), by specifying something like:

```
<input name="lol" placeholder="1234567890">
```

After that, use [a jQuery plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/Placeholder-jQuery-Plugin) to enable `placeholder`s on older browsers.

Comment: Yea, since not all browsers support html 5, I need a jquery version

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```
var holders = {
  "phone": "1234567890",
  "email": "address@domain.com"
  };
$(":text").each(function(){
  var id = this.id, $input = $(this);
  if(typeof holders[id] != 'undefined') {
    var $holder = $("<span class='prepopulation'>" + holders[id] + "</span>");
    if ($input.val().length != 0) $holder.hide();
    $input.parent().prepend($holder);
    $holder.click(function(){
      $input.focus()
      $holder.hide();
    });
    $input.blur(function(){
      if($input.val().length == 0) {
        $holder.show();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: That seems to be working, but the only problem with that is if there is already a value in the text box on page load (which there is sometimes), it also shows the holder value...

Comment: @Phil - Yes :) That's why I write "like this". The code that is presented in question, didn't add holder at all if there is already a value in the text box. You are right: there should be one more `.hide`  if `$input.val().length != 0`

Comment: Maybe to make this method more flexible it is useful to add wrapper (via this method) for each <input type="text"/>